# $v\in\mathcal{L}(F,E)$ such that $u\circ v\circ u=u$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $E,F$ two $\mathbb{K}$ vector spaces, $u\in\mathcal{L}(E,F)$.

a) Show that there exists $v\in\mathcal{L}(F,E)$ such that $u\circ v\circ u=u$

b) Can we additionally have $v\circ u\circ v=v$ ?

---

I have asked in the past [Existence of $v\in\mathcal{L}(E)$ such as $u=u\circ v\circ u$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/836438/existence-of-v-in-mathcalle-such-as-u-u-circ-v-circ-u), however here we are not talking about endomorphisms anymore. I have not managed to find an answer so far to any of the two questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can do it for the infinite-dimensional case using the Axiom of Choice.  I suspect it requires some form of this axiom.

Let $W$ be the null space of $u$, and extend a basis  $\{e_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in A}$  of $W$ to a basis $\{e_\beta\}_{\beta \in B}$ of $E$.  Then the range of $u$ is the linear span of $\{u e_\beta\}_{\beta \in B \backslash A}$, which are linearly independent.  Extend this to a basis $\{w_\gamma\}_{\gamma \in \Gamma}$.
Then we define $v$ to map $u e_\beta$ to $e_\beta$ for $\beta \in B \backslash A$
and all other $w_\gamma$ to $0$.  This satisfies both $u v u = u$ and $v u v = v$.

Comment: Cool stuff! And a much more concise treatment of what I had in mind.

Answer (score 1):

As with the last question you asked, the [Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse) will work here as long as $E$ and $F$ are finite dimensional inner product spaces.

Without using this, we could still make do, at least in the finite dimensional case:

---

Suppose $E$ and $F$ have dimensions $n$ and $m$.  Let $e_1,\dots,e_n$ be a basis for $E$ such that $u(e_1),\dots,u(e_r)$ gives a basis for the image of $u$ and $e_{r+1},\dots,e_n$ are in the kernel of $u$.

We can extend this into a basis $\{f_1 = u(e_1),\dots,f_r = u(e_r),f_{r+1},\dots,f_{m}\}$.  We define the map $v$ by $v(f_i) = e_i$ if $i \leq r$ and $0$ otherwise.

We now verify that $uvu = u$.  For $i \leq r$, we have
$$
uvu(e_i) = uv(f_i) = u(e_i)
$$
For $i > r$, we have $uvu(e_i) = u(e_i) = 0$.  So, $uvu(x) = u(x)$ for all $x \in E$.

Now, for $i \leq r$, we have
$$
vuv(f_i) = vu(e_i) = v(f_i)
$$
and for $i > r$, we have
$$
vuv(f_i) = v(f_i) = 0
$$
So, both conditions are satisfied.

---

I'm not sure if the same can be said for infinite dimensional vector-spaces.  Note my use of the rank-nullity theorem to ensure the numbers worked out correctly.